# как получить значение объекта "data" с класу B, который в приватном секторе класа А?

Tags: c++, ооп

Мне нужно получить значение **data** с класа **B** для дальнейшой работы с ним у public секторе класа **А**, при этотом клас **B** находиться у private секторе класа **А**. это возможно? Если да, то как это осуществить?

```
class A
{
public:
   
private:
    class B
    {
    public:
        int data;
    };
};
```

Comment: этот доступ разрешён в любом методе класса **A**. Вопрос помощи должен содержать проблему. Приведите свой неудачный пример.

Comment: Например  B().data, но не забывать про инициализацию членов при конструировании

Comment: Ещё, объявление класса создаёт тип, а не элемент. Далее, нужно добавить элемент класса **B** во внутрь класса **A**. `B b;` и обращение такое : `b . data = 7;`